# How to use `ng-bind` in directive for sorting the values

Tags: angularjs, sorting, angular-directive

I am getting the collection from controller to directive. where I am appending to template.

i required to achieve 2 things here

1. On load the collection - let it be sorted
2. On input change, ( model change ) requried to re-sort the array values.

for my try both not works. any one clarify the issue here and sort the issue?

here is my code :

```
   app.directive("customGrid", function($timeout,$filter){
  return{
    scope:{ 
      "pages":"="
    },
    template:temp.join(''),
    link : function( scope, element, attrs ){
      scope.slice = null;

      scope.sortIt = function( value ){
        scope.pages.pin = $filter('orderBy')( value, '');
        console.log( scope.pages.pin ); 
//consoles sorted not updating in view
        scope.$apply(); 
      }

      $timeout(function(){
       scope.slice = scope.pages.pin;

       scope.sortIt( scope.slice );

      })

    }
  }
})
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/btsvbZ7dglv9W0CvaO2p?p=preview)

Comment: are you trying to sort the item in the array even when new items to the array gets added or removed?

Comment: Yes exactly required to re-sort each time the mode changes

Comment: Why are you doing the sorting manually and not letting angular handle it by adding the filter to the `ng-repeat='(key,value) in pages | limitTo:3:1'`?

Comment: this is just a sample, for my case I required to set in directive

Comment: Can you update your plunker to show your attempt at sorting in the directive? In the plunker you attached there is no sorting code?

Comment: My sorting is not working as expected : http://plnkr.co/edit/btsvbZ7dglv9W0CvaO2p?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about that? using native angular sort with own filter, also passed whole objects to directive, as it might be tricky to work there with 3 separate, flat arrays. [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/S4ZyteTh6lFm7GxrD8qe?p=preview)

```
var temp = [
  "<ul><li ng-repeat='obj in slice | myOrder:obj:reverse'>",
  "<input ng-model='obj.pin' type='text'/></li></ul>"
  ]

app.filter('myOrder', function() {
  return function(items, field, reverse) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      filtered.push(item);
    });
    filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
      return (parseInt(a.pin) > parseInt(b.pin) ? 1 : -1);
    });
    if(reverse) filtered.reverse();
    return filtered;
  };
});



app.directive("customGrid", function($timeout,$filter){
  return{
    scope:{ 
      "pages":"="
    },
    template:temp.join(''),
    link : function( scope, element, attrs ){
      scope.slice = null;
      $timeout(function(){
       scope.slice = scope.pages;
       console.log(scope.slice,scope.pages)
      })


      //console.log( sorted ); //not sorting
    }
  }
})
```

**EDIT**
[Plnkr without orderBy](http://plnkr.co/edit/ja2uWybX4TUj6H4fZJtK?p=preview)
Still, it's hard to say without knowing details& requirements of the project. I can say, from own experience, it's often better to use some virtual-repeat techniques (or, in the case of tables, some dedicated vanilla scripts that work with Angular).

Comment: The main reason is to avoid number of `$watchers` - what I posted is small piece of data. I am have huge data set.